# Best method to get single value array from multi value array

Tags: php, arrays

Have array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Slot_id] => 7048,
            [name] => value
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Slot_id] => 7049,
            [name] => value
        )

)
```

I want to get the below array form

```
 Slot_id => Array
    (
       [0] => 7048,
       [1] => 7049
     )
```

currently i am using `foreach` function, any other best method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using PHP >= 5.5 then [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is the solution:

```
$result = array_column($input, 'Slot_id');
```

For earlier versions, either manually `foreach` or alternatively:

- with `array_map`:

  ```
  // assumes PHP 5.3 for lambda function, for earlier PHP just do foreach
  $result = array_map(function($row) { return $row['Slot_id']; }, $input);
  ```
- with `array_walk`:

  ```
  // assumes PHP 5.4 for short array syntax, for 5.3 use array() instead of []
  $result = [];
  array_walk($input, function($row) use (&$result) { $result[] = $row['Slot_id']; });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use array_column function:
https://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-column.php

```
$subArray = array_column ($your_array, 'Slot_id');
```